# Where to get Android 1.5 source?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm targeting Android 1.5 - I'd like to use the ScrollView widget, but there's a hard-coded value within the class which makes it kind of unusable for my purposes (it's the "touch slop" value - set to 16 - the amount of movement the user has to make with their finger before considering the gesture a scroll - I think this should ideally be cut in half!).

Anyway, I could grab the source of ScrollView, paste it into my project, and then tweak that one static field, then rename the class MyScrollView. But where is the 'official' source code for Android living, specifically for 1.5? I grabbed the ScrollView code from here as a test:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-1.6_r1/core/java/android/widget

but not sure if this is the right place to get it.

Comment: Be careful of redefining how common UI components work, otherwise users will be surprised and might get frustrated.  Sometimes it's better to be consistent than be hair-splittingly right.

Comment: I definitely agree about that. In this case, I think it might be ok. I need a scrollable surface which has the same sensitivity to start-scroll as a ListView (but ListView just isn't working for this UI design). So I figure this is an ok modification.

Comment: android.git.kernel.org is the official repository.

Comment: Why not try to change the value via Reflection? Its not a final field, so just find the field via reflection, set the modifier to public and assign the value you want it to be. Only a guess, I'm not sure whether android supports reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Same needed here. You can browse the [class history](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+log/master/core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java). Seems dangerous adapt the class but I didn't found another solution, I need to change the scroll sensibility and that's a private field (mTouchSlop)